# Use Android monitor to monitor memory usage of some app which is not build by android studio

Tags: android, ionic-framework, profiling

I have an ionic app and i want to monitor it's memory usage over time using **android monitor**.
How can i monitor my app without building and deploying it again with android studio. Is it possible to do such a thing. Monitor a pre-built app running in a device using it.